# Moving strings found within matched characters to a new column in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a set of data formatted like this:

```
01: <00-00-00> foo bar <00-00-01>
02: <00-00-01> bar foo <00-00-02>
```

and I would like to use grep to cut out the initial

```
: <xyz>
```

angle bracket strings and place them in a new column called V2. The last

```
<xyz>
```

angle bracket strings on each row should also be placed in a new column, V3.

The strings found within these brackets are variable; I would like to capture these regardless of their nature so long as they are found between open and closed angle brackets. The first bracketed string on each row is distinguished from the last by following a ": ". I tried using this, but it's not working:

```
data$timestamp.start <- grep("\\: <[^\\>]*\\>", as.character(data$V2), perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Admittedly a bit hamfisted, just using capture and character classes:

```
 df1223 <- data.frame(V1=c("01: <00-00-00> foo bar <00-00-01>",
                           "02: <00-00-01> bar foo <00-00-02>"), 
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 df1223$V2 <- sub("^[^<]+([<][^>]+[>]).+$", "\\1", df1223$V1)
 df1223$V3 <- sub("^[^<]+[<][^>]+[>][^<]+([<][^>]+[>]).?$", "\\1", df1223$V1)
 df1223
#-----------
                                 V1         V2         V3
1 01: <00-00-00> foo bar <00-00-01> <00-00-00> <00-00-01>
2 02: <00-00-01> bar foo <00-00-02> <00-00-01> <00-00-02>
```

You would "read" that first pattern as pass across all the non-"<", then put the first "<" and all next non-">"-characters and the next ">" in a capture class labeled "\1". Then all the rest to the end of string goes outside that capture class. The `sub` then only returns what in the capture class. The next call to `sub` just repeats the process with a similar pattern to find the second enclosed string but uses a "?" rather than a "+" because there might not be any characters after the end of the capture class.

Comment: This basically takes care of it! I added some code to get rid of the strings that were not enclosed in the second set of <> brackets in the V3 column, but otherwise this solution did the track, thanks!

Comment: It is whatever was matched by the first capture class. Read about them in `?regex`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you have following data frame.

```
df1223 <- structure(list(V1=c("01: <00-00-00> foo bar <00-00-01>"),V2=c("02: <00-00-01> bar foo <00-00-02>")),V3='NULL', class = ("data.frame"))
```

Now you could get the data between first `<>`:

```
gsub("([0-9]+: )(<[^>]*)(>)(.*)","\\2\\3",df1223$V1)
```

To get second set of string between `<>` use following.

```
gsub("([0-9]+: )(<[^<]*)(<.*>)","\\3",df1223$V1)
```

To be honest I spent lot of time on this that how I could insert into data frame since I am learning R too I couldn't do it, if you know that then this could help you.

Comment: That df1223 object is not the dataframe illustrated in the question